# php - php Thumb file not writeable

Tags: phpthumb

i'm using ffmpeg for extracting a video frame from which i want to create a thumbnail using php thumb.
creating the video frame works, but when trying to save the thumbnail file (under a different name - same directory) i'm getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'File is not writeable, and could not correct permissions: d:/Webs/bla.jpg' in D:\Webs\phpThumb\lib\GdThumb.inc.php:656
```

it can't be a permission problem as i can already store the videoframe into the same folder.

any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved it with saving the file with document_root:

```
$phpthumb->adaptiveResize(100, 100)->save($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/public/uploads/thumbs/filename.jpg');
```

Found the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17684098/317326