# How to save thumb with phpthumb?

Tags: php, phpthumb

```
require_once '../ThumbLib.inc.php';
$thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create('test.jpg');
$thumb->resize(100, 100)->save('/img/new_thumb.jpg');
$thumb->show();
```

I set 777 permission to img folder but I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'File not writeable: /img/new_thumb.jpg' in /home/xjohn/www.mysite.com/phpthumb/GdThumb.inc.php:662 Stack trace: #0 /home/xjohn/www.mysite.com/phpthumb/examples/resize_basic.php(31): GdThumb->save('/img/new_th...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/xjohn/www.mysite.com/phpthumb/GdThumb.inc.php on line 662
```

Why ?

Comment: I assume it's because the path is wrong - maybe it needs to be `/home/xjohn/www.mysite.com/img/new_thumb.jpg`? Though you might want to add something that will work it out programmatically.

Comment: I tryed this path but I get the same error

Comment: What's the full path of your img folder? That's the one you should be using.

Comment: /home/xjohn/www.mysite.com/phpthumb/imgnews/

Comment: Have you tried using that?

Comment: yes but doesn't work :(

Comment: In your question, you say the folder is called `img/`; in your comment, you say it's `imgnews/` - is one of those a typo?

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'File not writeable:
```

The error usually appears when your PHP script doesn't have sufficient permissions to create a file.

Here, you're using an absolute URL while saving the image:

```
$thumb->resize(100, 100)->save('/img/new_thumb.jpg');
```

If you want to use an absolute URL, you'll have to include the full path, like so:

```
$new_image = '/home/xjohn/www.mysite.com/phpthumb/img/new_thumb.jpg/';
$thumb->resize(100, 100)->save($new_image);
```

Alternatively, if the images are in the same directory as the script, you can just use relative paths:

```
$thumb->resize(100, 100)->save(__DIR__.'/my_new_image.jpg');
```

According to @OrangePill below:

It'd be better to use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` in your scripts for better maintainability.

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/phpthumb/img/new_thumb.jpg"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Alternative to absolute url would be to use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/phpthumb/img/new_thumb.jpg"`, this will keep it working between local and live.  The last instance is going to try to save it relative to where the request started, not nessessarily where this code is being called if you want it relative to where it is called it should be `__DIR__."/my_new_image.jpg"`